# Rails - validation inside decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, decorator

I'm struggling with some kind of issue. I have a rails model (mongoid).

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  validate :password_presence,
           :password_confirmation_match,
           :email_presence,

  field :email
  field :password_digest

 def password_presence
 end

 def email_presence
 end

 def password_confirmation_match
 end
end
```

My goal is to call validations depends on which decorator I will use. Let's say I've got two decorators:

```
class PasswordDecorator < Draper::Decorator
 def initialize(user)
   @user = user
 end
end

def RegistraionDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def initialize(user)
   @user = user
  end
end
```

So now when I create/save/update my user object inside RegistraionDecorator I would like to perform all validation methods.

```
RegistraionDecorator.new(User.new(attrbiutes))
```

But when I will do it inside PasswordDecorator I want to call for example only password_presence method.

```
PasswordDecorator.new(User.first)
```

When I move validations to decorator it won't work cuz its different class than my model.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What if you are creating a `User` object without calling it inside any decorator?

Comment: then all validations methods will be performed , however I would like to have more control on validation methods.

Comment: Validations should be present in model only. You can decide which validations to run based values of some `field`s or `attr_accessor`s whichever suits your case.

Comment: What is the criteria for deciding which decorator to use?

Comment: Could you give my any example?

Comment: Controllers are criterias.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128822/discussion-between-jagdeep-singh-and-mike927).

Comment: You should use a Service instead of a Decorator. Decorators are used to add dynamic behavior to objects. Services wraps object logic (such as save/update/delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a Form Object pattern instead.

Here is an example (from a real project) of how it could be done with [reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform).

```
class PromocodesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @form = PromocodeForm.new(Promocode.new)
  end

  def create
    @form = PromocodeForm.new(Promocode.new)

    if @form.validate(promo_params)
      Promocode.create!(promo_params)
      redirect_to promocodes_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def promo_params
    params.require(:promocode).
      permit(:token, :promo_type, :expires_at, :usage_limit, :reusable)
  end
end



class PromocodeForm < Reform::Form
  model :promocode

  property :token
  property :promo_type
  property :expires_at
  property :usage_limit
  property :reusable

  validates_presence_of :token, :promo_type, :expires_at, :usage_limit, :reusable
  validates_uniqueness_of :token

  validates :usage_limit, numericality: { greater_or_equal_to: -1 }
  validates :promo_type, inclusion: { in: Promocode::TYPES }
end
```

**Bonus:** The model does not trigger validations and much easy to use in tests.

Comment: awesome, that's solution I was looking for. I've not known reform before. Thanks!